# C programming (beginner help) Ascii table

Tags: c, visual-studio, ascii

Hi everybody need some help with C programming .
I need to write ascii table without numbers : 0, 7-10 , 13 . between every char will be "\t" and after every 10 chars it will skip line .
my code for now :

```
void ascii()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= 255; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            printf("\t");

        }
        if (0 == i % 10)
        {
            printf("\n");
        }       
        printf("%d = %c\t", i, i);

    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You could take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to have a global idea of how this site works, and read the [advice on how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) in the help center to see what questions are welcomed here and which are not.

Comment: What are you having trouble with?

Comment: it still show me the numbers 0, 7-10 , 13 in output

Comment: An ASCII table ends at codepoint 127. If you go to 255, you are using [some other](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding#Common_character_encodings) character set. Run `chcp` to find out. Note: [Windows-1252](http://unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WINDOWS/CP1252.TXT) has some holes so, although, it goes from 0 to 255, you should skip additional codepoints.

Answer (score 1):

Why are those codes excluded? Wouldn't it be better to exclude all non-printable codes? `isprint` will do just that.

```
    #include <ctype.h>

    if (isprint(i)) printf("%d = %c\t", i, i);
```

If you want to exclude those particular codes, you can use the same technique as the isxxx functions:

```
char is_print[256] = { 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1, /* 0 in pos 0, 7-10 and 13 */
                       1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                       1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                       1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                       1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                       1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                       1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                       1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                       1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                       1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                       1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                       1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                       1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                       1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                       1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                       1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
}; /* Filter with 0 for the chars we want to exclude. */ 

int myIsprint(char c) {
    return is_print((unsigned char)c); /* Use the filter */
}
```

And in your function:

```
if (myIsprint(i)) printf("%d = %c\t", i, i);
```

**Note:**

In simple cases you might as well just use an `if` that tests the particular codes `if (i != 0 && i != 13 && (i < 7 || i > 10)) print...`.
The filter technique described above has the advantage of being lightning fast, and the code easy to read, even if the number of cases is large.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap

```
printf("%d = %c\t", i, i);
```

in an `if`-statement which excludes the special cases:

```
if (!(i == 0 || (i >= 7 &% i <= 10) || i == 13)) {
    printf("%d = %c\t", i, i);
}
```